# Add App to Channel Programmatically using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to install a tab app to a specific channel inside a team using graph api. The relevant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-install-app-in-a-team-and-consent-to-the-resource-specific-permissions-required-by-the-app) seems to only include adding apps to the team itself, not a specific channel. However, from the Microsoft Teams UI I seem to be able to do so.[image]

I attempted to do a naive request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{{team_id}}/channel/{{channel_id}}/installedApps
```

That mimics the working flow for teams using the standard convention for other API calls to a specific channel, but to no luck.

I also attempted to add it via:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/tabs
```

With a request body:

```
{
  "displayName": "Your App Tab Display Name",
  "teamsAppId": "YourAppId",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "YourEntityId",
    "contentUrl": "YourContentUrl",
    "websiteUrl": "YourWebsiteUrl"
  }
}
```

But it returns a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a channel named **`General`** in my Teams group, that can be retrieved using below Graph API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/
```

**Response:**

[image]

Initially, you can call below Graph API query to get **`teamsAppId`** of **Forms** application:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps?$filter=displayName+eq+'Forms'
```

**Response:**

[image]

To install a tab app to a specific channel inside a team, I ran below Graph request and got **response** like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/tabs

{
    "displayName": "Forms Tab App",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{AppId_from_above_response}",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "YourEntityId",
        "contentUrl": "YourContentUrl",
        "websiteUrl": "YourWebsiteUrl"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Teams where tab application added successfully to channel like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Add tab to channel - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)